# Wrong Stats with Calculated Metrics

Tags: google-tag-manager

On this Website, https://webuynow.co.uk/ There are two tags set up, Both related to Form Submission. One is related to Half form Submission, & 2nd is related to Full Form Submission. One is fired when the user clicks on the Email Input field means half the lead logic track. And the other is fired when the full form is submitted. Full-Form Submission Fired.
Both are fired according to the set rules.
But The data that comes from both tags needs to be calculated. Because Sometimes A user submits a full form Submission. will also fire half lead form submission. I want to analyze my data more granularly.

But in Google Analytics I made a Custom report to analyze both stats. For me Both Tags are firing necessary & both are fired. . So for this distinguished I setup a Calculated metric with this condition "Full Form Submissions completions - Half lead form submission = Real Granular Data"

But in Analytics Calculated Metrics numbers are not trustworthy, That is the Real problem. Because According to our website Context half lead logic numbers needs to be greater than the full form submission, Because A user who submits the Full form Submission will definitely fire the Half Form Submission first.

First step:
Enter Postcode
2nd step:
Enter Your Address
3rd step:
Enter phone #
4th step:(Half Lead Logic Tag Fire)
Enter Email
5th & Last step:
Enter Full name
(Where Full Form Submission Fire)

GTM Debug Link

Click To view the Screenshots

Comment: [link](https://tagassistant.google.com/#/?id=GTM-5C77H24&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwebuynow.co.uk%2F%3Fgtm_debug%3D1663569322925&source=TAG_MANAGER&gtm_auth=PTKEpINBuTNBC5WdIrMz4A&gtm_preview=env-7)

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wP0ZxjXAx5osS9Uyr40ZnMiTugZ7rn-Y?usp=sharing)